# Jagged edges when using Glare in Compositor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have designed this jewel:

[image]

I am using Compositing nodes for the final render, to add a glare effect, as such:

[image]

But the result is that some of the edges of the golden shape are irregular where the glare is most present:

[image]

I have tried to change the settings in the Compositing nodes, which didn't do anything, and I can't seem to find a way to make the edges as sharp as they should be.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Is the render resolution set to 100%? Have you tried setting the quality in the glare node from medium to high?

Comment: @ShadyPuck I just added the .blend

Comment: @cegaton yes, I played around with the settings and never really got anything satisfying in terms of sharpness

Comment: @fabriced I must confess I don't really see anything obviously amiss in both circled regions.. What exactly are you looking for in terms of "sharpness"?

Comment: Unrelated, but I thought I'd mention that the alpha-over node in your setup isn't needed. If you want to mix between the original image and the glareified version, the *mix* setting on the glare node can be adjusted; `-1` is the original unmodified input, `0` is the glare + input, and `1` is just the glare (and everything in-between is a mix).

Comment: Changing the setting from Medium to High solved the problem! Please @cegaton make this an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @MicroMachine please write an answer for your question  and add details of what you did. I thought you weren't getting "anything satisfying" by changing the setting.

Comment: @cegaton true, maybe your suggestion became a more obvious answer after removing the useless "Alpha Over" Node, as suggested by gandalf3 after I said changing settings didn't work. I can write an answer, sorry if your feelings were hurt, your contributions have been very helpful across the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining cegaton and gandalf3's comments, I removed the useless **Alpha Over** node:

[image]

then switched the setting for the **Glare** node to "**High**":

[image]

This resolved the pixelation / jagged diagonal lines I was seeing:

[image]